# Update ttk.ProgressBar defined in other class Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a main class for my GUI, where i create a ttk.ProgressBar:

```
class MainApplication(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        #--Fenêtre principale

        self.title("MyApp")
        self.geometry('1000x500')

        self.notebook = ttk.Notebook(self)

        self.Page1 = Page1(self.notebook)
        self.Page2 = Page2(self.notebook)
        self.Page3 = Page3(self.notebook)
        self.Page4 = Page4(self.notebook)

        self.notebook.add(self.Page1, text='Page1')
        self.notebook.add(self.Page2, text='Page2')
        self.notebook.add(self.Page3, text='Page3')
        self.notebook.add(self.Page4, text='Page4')

        self.notebook.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)


        self.progress = ttk.Progressbar(self, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=490, mode='determinate')
        self.progress.pack()
```

I have a class for each page of my Notebook and i want update my progressbar when i run a function in my page2, I tried:

```
class Page2(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, container):
        super().__init__()

        self.send = ttk.Button(self, text='SEND', command=send_message)

        self.Button_envoyer.place(relx=0.01, rely=0.8)

    def send_message(self):

        self.progress.start()
        self.progress['value'] = 0
        self.update_idletasks()
        self.time.sleep(1)
        
        print("0%")

        self.progress['value'] = 50
        self.update_idletasks()
        self.time.sleep(1)

        print("50%")
       
        self.progress['value'] = 100
        self.update_idletasks()
        self.time.sleep(1)

        print("100%")

        self.progress.stop()
```

But I get the error message :

```
AttributeError: 'Page2' object has no attribute 'progress'
```

I simplified the code for be the most generalist possible.

How can I do that then?

Comment: You define the progress bar in `MainApplication`, but you try to use it in another completely unrelated class named `Page2`. How do you expect the progress bar to be transferred from one class to the other if you don't do it yourself? Did you mean to put the progress bar's creation and `pack()` in `Page2.__init__()`?

Comment: I have my progress bar in my main class, because its here I Create my GUI. I just want update ProgressBar value when I make Operations in others pages(in others classes)

Comment: Then maybe you could make a `progress_bar` argument for `Page2.__init__()`, so that `MainApplication` can create it as such: `self.Page2 = Page2(self.notebook, self.progress)`. Note that that'll require you to move the definition of `progress` above the creation of the `Page` classes.

Comment: you have `progressbar` in `MainApplication` so `Page2` would need some access to `MainApplication` but you don't send `self` to `Page2` to assing it as `parent`/`master` for `Frame`/`Page2`. If you would send `self` then you could use `self.master.progressbar`. At this moment you may eventually try to use `container` to access `MainApplication` but it is Notebook and it may need something like `self.parent.parent.progressbar`

Comment: You have to use`self.after()` to update the progressbar variable in ttk.frame application, i.e. your page2. something like this:  `self.after(100, self.master.master.prog_bar_update, counter)`. 
 here `prog_bar_update` is a function that you define for updating the progress bar in the main window. And again you have to call `self.update()` before the `self.after()` to get the variable updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `progressbar` in `MainApplication` so `Page2` would need some access to `MainApplication`.

Normally we send parent object as first argument in widgets i.e. `Button(root,...)` and later widget can use `self.master` to access parent object.

But you don't assign parent object in `super().__init__()` so it automatically set `tk.Tk` as parent. And if you use `self.master` then you should have access to `MainApplication`

```
self.master.progressbar.start()

# etc.
```

```
Page2
  | 
  | .master
  V
MainApplication
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you would assign `Notebook` (`container`) as master/parent for `Page2`

```
class Page2(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, container):
        super().__init__(container)  # <-- `container` as parent
```

then you would need

```
self.master.master.progressbar.start()

# etc.
```

```
Page2
  | 
  | .master
  V
Notebook
  |
  | .master
  V
MainApplication
```